# Using AppCenter Crashes.ShouldAwaitUserConfirmation from WPF/Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using AppCenter SDK from some Winforms and WPF apps.  Generally all good except I'm trying to implement the [Crashes.ShouldAwaitUserConfirmation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/wpf-winforms#customize-your-usage-of-app-center-crashes) callback and failing miserably. The crash is always logged on the app center but the user confirmation task dialog is ever appearing and I'm struggling to find any sample code or docs that explain this.

```
        Crashes.ShouldAwaitUserConfirmation = () =>
        {
            Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.TaskDialogButton buttonSend = new Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.TaskDialogButton("Send");
            Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.TaskDialogButton buttonAlwaysSend = new Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.TaskDialogButton("Always Send");
            Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.TaskDialogButton buttonDontSend = new Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.TaskDialogButton("Don't Send");

            Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.TaskDialog taskDialog = new Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.TaskDialog();
            taskDialog.Buttons.Add(buttonSend);
            taskDialog.Buttons.Add(buttonAlwaysSend);
            taskDialog.Buttons.Add(buttonDontSend);

            taskDialog.WindowTitle = "Error";
            taskDialog.MainInstruction = "Do you want to send this error report to the developer?";

            var result = taskDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == buttonSend)
            {
                Crashes.NotifyUserConfirmation(UserConfirmation.Send);
            }
            else if (result == buttonAlwaysSend)
            {
                Crashes.NotifyUserConfirmation(UserConfirmation.AlwaysSend);
            }
            else
            {
                Crashes.NotifyUserConfirmation(UserConfirmation.DontSend);
            }

            return true;
        };

        AppCenter.Start("<SECRET>", typeof(Crashes));
```

Comment: Did you try to implement a callback without dialog implementation inside (I mean just empty callback)? Is it still crashing? What version of App Center SDK do you use? What error do you get?

Comment: I got it working (sort of) by adding this code `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);` instead of `Application.ThreadException += (sender, args) => {Crashes.TrackError(args.Exception);};`. Now I get the task dialog on next restart of the app. But I would have expect to see the task dialog pop everytime I call `Crashes.TrackError()` but its not....it just sends the error.  Using version 4.4.0

Comment: Yes, `Crashes.TrackError` API is used for the handled errors. Please see docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/wpf-winforms#handled-errors

Comment: I get that.  But if your asking for users consent to send data why doesn’t it apply to trackerrors?

Comment: Dialog about crash appears after a fatal crash which broke application work. `Crashed.TrackError` API, as `Analytics.TrackEvent` API, send your own analytics data about the work of your application. If you don’t want to send any data without user confirmation then you can use this API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/other-apis/wpf-winforms#disallow-network-requests

Comment: Ok, thanks for that explanation @Anastasia